# Multi-condition formatting on Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I've got a dataframe looks like this:

```
    x   y   z
0   1   0   10
1   1   10  400
2   1   10  95
```

To reproduce the data frame, use the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'x': [1,1,10], 'y': [0,10,10], 'z': [10,400,95]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Blanks are filled with 0, hence all cells have a value present.

I want to run/apply a set of conditions on this DF such that:

1. If column Y has a value == 0, then replace the value with 'red: 0'
2. If column Z has a value > 300, then replace the value with 'red: {value}'
3. If column Z has a value > 90, then replace the value with 'yellow: {value}'

Basically I'm trying to convert a DF into a wiki table with some conditional color formatting applied. After the formatting it should look like:

```
|=x|=y|=z
|1|'red: 0'|10
|1|10|'red: 400'
|1|10|'yellow: 95'
```

Is there a clean way of doing this?

PS: There are two original datasources, list of dictionary and a nested dictionary which was converted into a DF. Any idea if it's easier to do outside of Pandas?

Comment: value which is greater than 300 will  be greater than 90 as well...you need to look at the condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
z = df.z.astype(str)
df.y = df.y.replace(0, 'red: 0')
df.z = np.where(df.z > 300, 'red: '+ z,
       np.where(df.z > 90, 'yellow: '+ z,df.z))
print (df)
   x       y           z
0  1  red: 0          10
1  1      10    red: 400
2  1      10  yellow: 95
```

Another solution with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df.y = df.y.replace(0, 'red: 0')
z = df.z.astype(str)

m1 = df.z > 300
m2 = df.z > 90
df.z = np.select([m1, m2 & ~m1], ['red: ' + z, 'yellow: '+ z], default=df.z)
print (df)
   x       y           z
0  1  red: 0          10
1  1      10    red: 400
2  1      10  yellow: 95
```